# I can't fix my tire

Tags: tire, innertube, installation

Alright so I got a flat tire. Got a new tube because the old one is punctured. Got the tube inside the tire but now the tire looks like it doesn't quite fit the tube. Even the old tube it doesn't close it when inflated (I patched the hole). It just it's very weird looking and when I try to ride my bike with it, it slips. There's a photo attached. It's a mountain bike.I basically don't know how to install a tube into the tire.[image]

Comment: Can you show a photo from a different angle? Its a bit hard to make out what's going on, but it seems that the bead is off the rim a bit.

Comment: Watch this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnP6coXzbLY

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have the bead outside the rim.

Here's a schematic from Wikimedia, of an installed tire. It looks like you have left the part labeled 4 on the outside.

[image: Schematic of an installed tire. CC-By-SA-3.0 by Wikimedia user Deerwood]

How you can fix this is, put a bit of air into the tube so it doesn't get pinched, and then push the bead inside the rim. You may be able to do it by hand. The last twenty or so centimeters may require [tire levers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/1960/33466) (it seems a lot of puncture repair kits have those these days) to get on, but with some care you can use just about any tool.

For a more complete tutorial, you can see Howcast's tutorial on Youtube that mattnz linked in comments:

Comment: So the problem was that I didn't pinch in the tire into the rim, I just covered the tire with the rim when I should have grabbed the ends of the tire and pinched them into the rim before I inflated the tube.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @K17 you're welcome. If you found this answer helpful, you can accept it using the green checkmark button.